# Mendeley Implicit auth type not returning full data

Tags: mendeley

This question relates to the Mendeley API.
http://dev.mendeley.com/

When using the implicit auth type: http://dev.mendeley.com/reference/topics/authorization_overview.html

I seem to only receive a subset of data for a given document. For example, the 'websites' field seems to not come through even when it is populated.

I am only experiencing this issue using the implicit auth type and not other auth types.

Are any other Mendeley API users experiencing this? It seems like a bug.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please edit your question.  You can find information about how to compose a good question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Hopefully my question is more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certain fields get returned depending on the document view that you specify. This was implemented to be able to support the needs of multiple clients e.g. mobile clients require smaller datasets than larger web clients

Please read - http://dev.mendeley.com/methods/#document-views

You need to specify 'view=bib' on your endpoint call.

Here is a very crude worked example just using Java

```
@Test
public void testImplicitGrantFlow() {

    String random = RandomStringUtils.random(5);

    String query = String.format(
            "?client_id=%s&redirect_uri=%s&response_type=token&scope=all&state=%s", IMPLICIT_GRANT_FLOW_CLIENT_ID, "http://localhost:5000/callback", random);

    ClientResponse authorise = jerseyClient.resource(AUTH_URL + query)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .get(ClientResponse.class);

    assertThat(authorise.getStatus()).isEqualTo(200);

    ClientResponse postFormDataResponse = jerseyClient.resource(AUTH_URL + query)
            .entity("username=joyce.stack@mendeley.com&password=spuds", MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(ClientResponse.class);
    assertThat(postFormDataResponse.getStatus()).isEqualTo(302);

    String queryString = postFormDataResponse.getHeaders().get("Location").get(0);

    Matcher matcher = ACCESS_TOKEN_REGEX.matcher(queryString);
    matcher.find();
    String accessToken = matcher.group(1);

    matcher = STATE_REGEX.matcher(queryString);
    matcher.find();
    String state = matcher.group(1);

    assertNotNull(accessToken);
    assertThat(queryString).contains(accessToken);

    assertNotNull(state);
    assertThat(queryString).contains(state);

    ClientResponse response = jerseyClient.resource(OAuthBaseClass.DOCUMENTS_URL)
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
            .get(ClientResponse.class);
    assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(200);

    List<Document> documents = response.getEntity(new GenericType<List<Document>>() {
    });
    assertThat(documents.size()).isGreaterThan(0);

    ListIterator<Document> documentListIterator = documents.listIterator();
    while (documentListIterator.hasNext()) {
        Document next = documentListIterator.next();
          System.out.println(next.getTitle());
          System.out.println(next.getWebsites());

    }

}
```